# Will having too many conditionals break a HOC in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-functions, higher-order-components, mutation

I am trying to make a simple [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) in react. Its a supposed to render a `<Link/>` based on some props which I am using in conditionals to render my element.

I think the problem in one instance my desired result is a button which will render `Log out` if the `isLoggedIn` and the `anchorText` props are both false , and `Log in` if their true...

***AND***

I want that generic component to render an element `isLoggedIn` and the `anchorText` props are true and return nothing i.e. `null` if false...

Here it the HOC:

```
function GenericLoggedInLink({ isLoggedIn, logOutUser, route,anchorText }) {
 if ((isLoggedIn) && (anchorText === undefined)) {
  return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
 } else {
  return <Link href="/login"><a>Log in!</a></Link>
 }
 if ((isLoggedIn) && (anchorText)) {
 return <Menu.Item><Link href={route}><a>{anchorText}</a></Link></Menu.Item>
 } else {
  return null;
 }
}
```

And these are the Components being used;

```
<Menu.Item>
  <GenericLoggedInLink
    isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
    route="/profile"
    anchorText="Profile"
   />
   </Menu.Item>
   <Menu.Item>
    <GenericLoggedInLink
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      route="/dashboard"
      anchorText="Dashboard"
     />
   </Menu.Item>

<Menu.Item position='right'>
  <Button inverted={!fixed}>
   <GenericLoggedInLink 
    isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}    
    logOutUser={logOutUser}/>
 </Button>
</Menu.Item>
```

In VS code I actually get an error that the second conditional is unreachable? Can anyone help?

**UPDATE**

I tried what Cereal suggested, but now when the prop `isLoggedIn === false` the `Log In` is correct but the other links show this:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the second conditional unreachable because of the else return? I mean isn't that the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second conditional *is* unreachable.

In your first conditional, you *always* return from the function. If you're logged in and the anchor text is undefined, you return from the function. In *all other cases* you return from the function.

To fix this, you want to continue checking other conditions inside your else, essentially.

```
 if(isLoggedIn) {
   if(anchorText === undefined) {
     return <Link href="/"><a onClick={() => logOutUser()}>Log out!</a></Link>
   } else if(anchorText) {
     return <Menu.Item><Link href={route}><a>{anchorText}</a></Link></Menu.Item>
   } else {
     return null;
   }
 } else {
   return <Link href="/login"><a>Log in!</a></Link>
 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! As soon as I read it I was like YES!!! However I updated my question as now there is some funkiness happening?!  Could you please take a look? It's leaving me scratching my head, as that makes sense to me . ...now lol!

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz Seems as though you want a condition in the else block for if anchorText === undefined, then return null. Otherwise return the login button

Comment: Gave it a try but I think I wound up making it worse? Do you have time to illustrate what you mean?